# Wicket display pdf on Page x? (java)

Tags: java, wicket

I would like to add a functionality that shows a pdf on a certain page. I have the pdf as a File in my code. So I cannot get it from my webserver.

I also have the pagenumber. 
I've seen that the adobe plugin accepts #page=1 but I don't know how to use this in a web based application.

I also found some tutorials wich display it in an Iframe. But these use :

```
      org.apache.wicket.markup.html.DynamicWebResource
```

And this doesn't exist anymore.

I found it's replaced by

```
      org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ByteArrayResource
```

Are there any tutorials/tips on how to do this (Wicket 1.5 or higher)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify the data from you're object tag pass a pagenumber. This passes the page to the adobe plugin and automatically sets the page. (I have only tested this in chrome 21 and IE9)

```
    <object wicket:id="myFile" data="" border="1" width="100%" height="600px"></object>

    WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("myFile");
    wmc.add(new AttributeModifier("data", (String) urlFor(rr, null)+"#page="+ pageNmbr));
    add(wmc);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ResourceLink with ByteArrayResource, or you can use any link/button and in its onClick/onSubmit() you can do:

```
getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(
    new ResourceRequestHandler(new ByteArrayResource(...)))
```

In both cases you may need to set the content-disposition header by overriding `org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ByteArrayResource#configureResponse()` and calling `ResourceResponse#setContentDisposition(INLINE)` for it.

Comment: I'm now using resource reference is that the same as resource link?